# How to write a function to return a list element by using the list and integer as the arguments

Tags: python

I'm working on a problem where I need to define a function (`get_element`) that accepts two parameters (a list and an integer) and then returns a list element by its index position using the supplied integer as the index position value.

I'm given a list (`more_elements = ["salad", 33, 3.14, ['dog','cat'], "fish", 19, 18]`) to test my function on.

```
def get_element(a_list, a_int):
    for a_int in a_list:
        int(a_int)
    return a_list[a_int]
```

This is what my current code is. When I try to run it, however, I get an error `invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'salad'`

I'm not sure what this error means. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This seems like a homework question. Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) under "Asking about homework". I appreciate that you've put in effort to write your own code, but you don't seem to understand how it works at all.

Comment: If it weren't homework, I would say to use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)

Answer (score 1):

For the solution of your problem you do not need the for-loop, as your return call already fullfills the requirements.

The error occurs because you are trying to convert the string ('salad') into a number, which will not work in base 10 space ;). Basically the way you are using the for loop now you are iterating (looping) over 'a_list' and trying to convert each element into an integer, but this will very likely fail for most strings and lists inside this list.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I was going to say! Also worth noting that doing `for a_int in ...` overwrites the `a_int` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

here is how you would do it manually :

```py
get_element(some_list, some_index):
    if some_index < 0:
            some_index = some_index + len(some_list)
    i = 0
    for element in some_list:
        if i == some_index:
            return element
        i += 1
    print("index out of range")
    return
```

but normally you don't need a function for that, as you can directly get any element of a list by its index doing this :

```py
some_element = some_list[some_index]
```

also, you made a mistake here :

```py
def get_element(a_list, a_int):
    for a_int in a_list:
```

you are iterating for `a_int` in the list, which is already defined as an argument, you need to iterate using a different variable.

Comment: yeah but I'm required to write a function for it. It's a homework assignment.

Comment: I edited the answer to include a manual way of doing it, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from your description:

```
def get_element(list_of_element, element_index):
    try:
        return list_of_element[element_index]
    except IndexError:
        return 'index out of range'

# Call your function
print(get_element(["salad", 33, 3.14, ['dog','cat'], "fish", 19, 18], 12))  # Change the 12 by the index you want.
```

Comment: Why do you catch the `IndexError`?

Comment: If the given index is greater than the list length, this will raise an `IndexError` exception, isn't that?

Comment: yeah but why do you catch it instead of letting it propagate?